# How to check in Z3py whether the expression contains a conditional (=>)

Tags: z3, z3py

i'm using Z3py to traverse a Boolean formula. How to check whether the    formula contains a conditional. I have checked the z3.py source code and it contains `is_and()`, `is_or()`, `is_not()`,.. but nothing related to `is_implies()`. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an expert of `z3`, but `a -> c` is basically `!a v c`... where `a` and `c` can be anything. **e.g.** `b v c` is `!b -> c` and also `!c -> b`, `!a v !b v c` is `a -> (!b v c)` and also `b -> (!a v c)` and also `!c -> (!a v !b)` and also `(a & b) -> c` and also `...`. So `is_or()` should be sufficient, no?

Comment: Oh, I'm writing code for implication elimination.  So first i have to somehow parse that the code contains implication(condition to be precise). then i'll transformation a => b to !a Or b. Thanks.

Comment: I guess that means you are happy enough to catch explicit only implications, rather than all of them, so my comment is not relevant. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function "is_app_of" to determine the built-in function of an expression. Thus,

```
def is_and(a):
    return is_app_of(a, Z3_OP_AND)
```

as already implemented in the z3.py file, and similarly

```
def is_implies(a):
    return is_app_of(a, Z3_OP_IMPLIES)
```

Comment: Thanks. Great to know.